# FFMpeg 4.2 MacBook Pro 2018/19 consistent hard system crashing

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, macbook, macbook-pro

We've upgraded to newer MacBook Pro's and found that FFmpeg is now crashing the entire system after recording video for a few minutes. This isn't just an FFmpeg crash, it's an entire system crash, i.e. the screen goes black and the computer restarts. The crash is consistent and happens every single time without exception, rendering ffmpeg unusable for our team.

Here is the command which triggers the crash. I've downloaded both 4.2 and the latest development build, both of which crash.

```
ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 512 -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -async 1 -i "1" -thread_queue_size 512 -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0":"0" -s 640x400 -b:v 356k -aq 64k -filter:a "volume=1.0"  -filter_complex "[0]scale=128:80 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -movflags +faststart "test.mp4"
```

Here are the systems I've tested on. All are running macOS Mojave (10.14.6). The previous 2 MacBooks we were using don't have this crash (regardless of FFmpeg version) and they ran macOS Mojave (10.14.6) as well.  Any suggestions to fix this? FFmpeg is totally broken an not usable for Mac users currently.

Crashes:

- Macbook Pro 13" 2019 (Model Identifier 15,2)
- Macbook Pro 13" 2018 (Model Identifier 15,2)

Doesn't crash:

- Macbook Pro 13" Early 2015
- Macbook Air 2018

**EDIT**: After [posting a bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8110#ticket) they said this is a hardware problem that isn't related to user software so they will be ignoring it. We've test on 3 MacBook Pros (all 15,2 models) and get the same system crash.

Comment: Does it happen with file inputs (not avfoundation) ? Does it happen with 4.1?

Comment: Yes it did happen with 4.1. Can you provide a test command I could use? I took over development of an app which uses ffmpeg but I'm not very familiar with it myself. I'll be able to test tomorrow when I have access to the affect MacBook.

Comment: `ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 512 -async 1 -i some_video_file -thread_queue_size 512 -i some_audio_file -s 640x400 -b:v 356k -aq 64k -filter:a "volume=1.0" -filter_complex "[0]scale=128:80 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -movflags +faststart "test.mp4"`

Comment: I was able to convert a short video but I need some longer 5min + tests to test more. Why is this important though?

Comment: To identify the source of the crash. Do you have multiple machines of the new model and if yes, does the crash happen on all? iOS version?

Comment: I only have a MacBook Pro 2018/2019. Haven't ever tried on iOS. Is there an official bug report forum to FFMpeg do you know? It seems like the devs should know about this because it's so serious.

Comment: Sorry, I meant OS version, as in MacOS. You can file a bug report at trac.ffmpeg.org. Share the logs for git master there.

Comment: 10.14.6 for all systems being tested so the actual hardware seems to be the problem.

Comment: The bug report was closed since they feel this isn't a user software problem (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8110#ticket). I'll start looking for other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I use FFmpeg on a MacBook Air (2018) and a MacBook Air (2019) but running macOS Mojave (10.14.6) and have never had an issue. I use FFmpeg as installed via Homebrew. I would suggest uninstalling your application installed versions and just install it via Homebrew and see if that helps.

Comment: Jack, we've tested on 2018 MacBook Airs and they are fine. Just the 2018/19 MacBook Pros.

Comment: I wonder if any other CPU intensive processes cause the same issue. Is it simply overheating? Interesting that it occurs on more than one machine. Does it only crash with downloaded ffmpeg? What about compiling ffmpeg from the git master branch?

Comment: I was able to run just a screen recording command with ffmpeg that doesn't crash and still uses high CPU usage. I did try a build from homebrew but I don't think that's the master branch. I'll try to build from git tomorrow when I have access to the MacBooks. In the mean time I've filed a bug report with Apple since I think this is a hardware problem.

Comment: You can use homebrew to compile git master. Add the `--HEAD` option. See [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg) if you want additional components not offered by the default tap.

Comment: As a last resort I installed the Catalina Beta and the problem was resolved. Apple must have fixed something but FFMpeg is still broken on newer hardware unless you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Catalina Beta on the affected MacBook Pro's has fixed the problem. Evidently this was a hardware problem that Apple was able to fix in a later OS release.

EDIT: I just downloaded the 10.14.6 supplemental update and this has also fixed the crashing!

Comment: I added the relevant comment on the FFmpeg bug report.